# Params without value in URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

I'd like to get an `a=1&b=2&foo` URL with `URLSearchParams`.

Here's what I tried:

```js
new URLSearchParams([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['foo']]).toString();
// Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URLSearchParams':
// Failed to construct 'URLSearchParams': Sequence initializer must only contain pair elements

new URLSearchParams([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['foo', '']]).toString();
// a=1&b=2&foo=

new URLSearchParams([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['foo', null]]).toString();
// a=1&b=2&foo=null

new URLSearchParams([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['foo', undefined]]).toString();
// a=1&b=2&foo=undefined
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look possible. The URL standard [says that](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-urlsearchparams-urlsearchparams) the query object that a URLSearchParams has internally is a list of name-value pairs, and that when stringified, it runs the
[application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-urlencoded-serializer) serializer, which does:

```
Set encoding to the result of getting an output encoding from encoding.
Let output be the empty string.
For each tuple of tuples:
  Let name be the result of running percent-encode after encoding with encoding, tuple’s name, the application/x-www-form-urlencoded percent-encode set, and true.
  Let value be the result of running percent-encode after encoding with encoding, tuple’s value, the application/x-www-form-urlencoded percent-encode set, and true.
  If output is not the empty string, then append U+0026 (&) to output.
  Append name, followed by U+003D (=), followed by value, to output.
Return output.
```

Due to that final line in the loop, a `=` is always appended regardless of value.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `toString` and use a regex to remove the `=` after parameters with no value.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['foo', ''], ['bar', '']])
                .toString().replace(/=(?=&|$)/gm, '');

console.log(params)
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but it's not the point.

Comment: Is `m` flag useful here? Does `URLSearchParams().toString()` ever insert new line character?